# Wrong results when converting RGBA array into UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, uiimage

I'm trying to create an UIImage from a ARGB raw array.

First of all I create an array of 640x480 pixels (307200) and set all of them red.

```
var rgbArray = [Int?](repeating: nil, count: 307200)
for i in 0 ..< 307200 {
    rgbArray[i] = 0x00ff0000 // Red pixel
}
```

Now the image conversion:

```
let data = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: rgbArray)

let releaseMaskImagePixelData: CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback = { (info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, data: UnsafeRawPointer, size: Int) -> () in
    return
}

let provider: CGDataProvider! = CGDataProvider(dataInfo: nil, data: data, size: 307200, releaseData: releaseMaskImagePixelData)
    
let cgImage = CGImage(
    width: 640,
    height: 480,
    bitsPerComponent: 8,
    bitsPerPixel: 32,
    bytesPerRow: 2560,
    space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
    bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue),
    provider: provider,
    decode: nil,
    shouldInterpolate: true,
    intent: .defaultIntent
)
    
let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
```

the result is an image like this:

[image]

Note that the image is blue instead of red, and also that strange vertical lines.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could just use Array repeating initializer to create that array in real time `[Int](repeating: 0x00ff0000, count: 307200)` would be done in real time

Comment: btw red pixel UIColor  in hexa should be `0xffff0000`

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself.

It was because of the type of rgbArray (Int?), if I don't make it optional it works fine, for example:

```
var rgbArray = [Int](repeating: 0xffff0000, count: 307200)
```

I can't still understand this weird behaviour but at least I got it working.